# How to make right side of page scroll and left side not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So as the title states, I'm trying to make one side of my website scroll, and the other side stay. I've found an example that does exactly what I want:

http://melaniedaveid.com/

If you scroll down a bit on that website you will see that the left side with the "about" will stand still and the right side with the text will scroll down if you scroll down. Does anyone have any idea on how to do this?

So far I just have 2 divs that are next to eachother.

```
<section class="about">
<div class="aboutTitle">
    about
</div>

<div class="aboutText">
    <p style="font-size: 50px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
</section>

.aboutTitle {
display: table-cell;
background-color: red;
float: left;
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
}

.aboutText {
display: table-cell;
background-color: orange;
float: left;
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
}
```

EDIT:

Sagar Kodte his solution worked fine for me. 1 thing that I didn't include in my original post, because I didn't think it was important in this case, was that I have another section above my "about" section.

```
    <body>

<section class="home">
Welcome
</section>

<section class="about">
    <div class="aboutTitle">
        about
    </div>

    <div class="aboutText">
        <p style="font-size: 50px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
</section>

</body>

.home {
background-color: grey;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
height: 100vh;
```

}

As soon as I removed the "home" section it started to work. But ofcourse I still want to be able to use that "home" section. Does anyone have an idea how I can use both sections and still use the scroll on one side thing?

**JSFiddle**: [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/sandeepb/uhs2qc7o/)

Comment: keep left side as position:fixed in css

Comment: This looks interesting i have added fiddle to your question.

Comment: you have to detect scrollTop and make the left div's position fixed and later after scrolling entire right div you need to change the left div's position attribute

Comment: You could add scrollbars to only that div with scrolling `overflow-y:scroll;`

Comment: The website you mentioned used jquery for this. if you want to take a look here is function they used. http://melaniedaveid.com/assets/js/plugins.min.js?v=1.8 cc- @sagarkodte

Comment: Yes brother. I saw it. Because of I want to learn something new that's why I am trying to make on my own.

Comment: @maxgeraci this is called Parallax-Effect. When googling you'll find quite a lot of examples and tutorials. ;)

Answer (score 2):

To perform the advanced effect wich tracks the scrollbar position, you would need jQuery. If you want a simple version of the divided page without this effect, here it is:

Let the body margin equal to zero. Then, divide the page in 2 divs both `width: 50%;` `height: 100%` and, finally, add `overflow-y: scroll` to the second div.

[**- codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YqyZez)

[**- jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/2cbtz4e8/)

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0px;
}

#a, #b {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#a {
  background: tomato;
}

#b {
  text-align: justify;
  background: honeydew;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#aboutimg {
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/q0NYMxY.png" alt=about id=aboutimg>
<div id=a><span style="font-size: 1.3em">About:</span></div><div id=b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nam nibh. Nunc varius facilisis eros. Sed erat. In in velit quis arcu ornare laoreet. Curabitur adipiscing luctus massa. Integer ut purus ac augue commodo commodo. Nunc nec mi eu justo tempor consectetuer. Etiam vitae nisl. In dignissim lacus ut ante. Cras elit lectus, bibendum a, adipiscing vitae, commodo et, dui. Ut tincidunt tortor. Donec nonummy, enim in lacinia pulvinar, velit tellus scelerisque augue, ac posuere libero urna eget neque. Cras ipsum. Vestibulum pretium, lectus nec venenatis volutpat, purus lectus ultrices risus, a condimentum risus mi et quam. Pellentesque auctor fringilla neque. Duis eu massa ut lorem iaculis vestibulum. Maecenas facilisis elit sed justo. Quisque volutpat malesuada velit.<br><br> 

Nunc at velit quis lectus nonummy eleifend. Curabitur eros. Aenean ligula dolor, gravida auctor, auctor et, suscipit in, erat. Sed malesuada, enim ut congue pharetra, massa elit convallis pede, ornare scelerisque libero neque ut neque. In at libero. Curabitur molestie. Sed vel neque. Proin et dolor ac ipsum elementum malesuada. Praesent id orci. Donec hendrerit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean sit amet arcu a turpis posuere pretium.<br><br> 

Nulla mauris odio, vehicula in, condimentum sit amet, tempus id, metus. Donec at nisi sit amet felis blandit posuere. Aliquam erat volutpat. Cras lobortis orci in quam porttitor cursus. Aenean dignissim. Curabitur facilisis sem at nisi laoreet placerat. Duis sed ipsum ac nibh mattis feugiat. Proin sed purus. Vivamus lectus ipsum, rhoncus sed, scelerisque sit amet, ultrices in, dolor. Aliquam vel magna non nunc ornare bibendum. Sed libero. Maecenas at est. Vivamus ornare, felis et luctus dapibus, lacus leo convallis diam, eget dapibus augue arcu eget arcu.<br><br>

Fusce auctor, metus eu ultricies vulputate, sapien nibh faucibus ligula, eget sollicitudin augue risus et dolor. Aenean pellentesque, tortor in cursus mattis, ante diam malesuada ligula, ac vestibulum neque turpis ut enim. Cras ornare. Proin ac nisi. Praesent laoreet ante tempor urna. In imperdiet. Nam ut metus et orci fermentum nonummy. Cras vel nunc. Donec feugiat neque eget purus. Quisque rhoncus. Phasellus tempus massa aliquet urna. Integer fringilla quam eget dolor. Curabitur mattis. Aliquam ac lacus. In congue, odio ut tristique adipiscing, diam leo fermentum ipsum, nec sollicitudin dui quam et tortor. Proin id neque ac pede egestas lacinia. Curabitur non odio.<br><br> 

Nullam porta urna quis mauris. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec scelerisque quam vitae est. Aenean vitae diam at erat pellentesque condimentum. Duis pulvinar nisl sed orci. Vivamus turpis nisi, volutpat in, placerat et, pharetra nec, eros. Suspendisse tellus metus, sodales non, venenatis a, ultrices auctor, erat. In ut leo nec elit mattis pellentesque. Sed eros elit, cursus accumsan, sollicitudin a, iaculis quis, diam. Pellentesque fermentum, pede a nonummy varius, ligula velit laoreet erat, et lacinia nibh nulla sit amet nunc. Suspendisse at turpis quis augue pellentesque pretium. Nunc condimentum elit semper felis.<br><br> 

Duis imperdiet diam pharetra nisi. Fusce accumsan. Fusce adipiscing, felis non ornare egestas, risus elit placerat mauris, in mollis ante erat quis nisi. Quisque sed ipsum. Nulla facilisi. Donec arcu erat, sodales quis, cursus eget, posuere eget, tellus. Vestibulum eu risus. Curabitur adipiscing, odio in pretium feugiat, nulla magna vehicula lorem, at placerat tortor nisl eget velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Suspendisse mollis fermentum massa. </div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the scroll work while your mouse is also inside the left div? So far you can only scroll down the text while your mouse hovers over the right div.

Answer (score 1):

This is my second answer on this question. The objective is to let the scroll working even with the mouse above the left box. Unlike the earlier version, the div with the content, on the right, have no scrollbar. Its content rolls with the page scrollbar. To avoid the page scrollbar of also reaches the first div, it was set with `position:fixed`

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0px;
}

#a, #b {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  display: inline-block;  
  vertical-align: top;
}

#a {
  padding-left: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: tomato;
  width: 50%;
}

#b {
  padding-left: calc(50% + 50px);
  text-align: justify;
  background: honeydew;
  width: 100%;
}

#aboutimg {
position: fixed;
top: 20px;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/q0NYMxY.png" alt=about id=aboutimg>
<div id=a><span style="font-size: 1.3em">About:</span></div><div id=b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nam nibh. Nunc varius facilisis eros. Sed erat. In in velit quis arcu ornare laoreet. Curabitur adipiscing luctus massa. Integer ut purus ac augue commodo commodo. Nunc nec mi eu justo tempor consectetuer. Etiam vitae nisl. In dignissim lacus ut ante. Cras elit lectus, bibendum a, adipiscing vitae, commodo et, dui. Ut tincidunt tortor. Donec nonummy, enim in lacinia pulvinar, velit tellus scelerisque augue, ac posuere libero urna eget neque. Cras ipsum. Vestibulum pretium, lectus nec venenatis volutpat, purus lectus ultrices risus, a condimentum risus mi et quam. Pellentesque auctor fringilla neque. Duis eu massa ut lorem iaculis vestibulum. Maecenas facilisis elit sed justo. Quisque volutpat malesuada velit.<br><br> 

Nunc at velit quis lectus nonummy eleifend. Curabitur eros. Aenean ligula dolor, gravida auctor, auctor et, suscipit in, erat. Sed malesuada, enim ut congue pharetra, massa elit convallis pede, ornare scelerisque libero neque ut neque. In at libero. Curabitur molestie. Sed vel neque. Proin et dolor ac ipsum elementum malesuada. Praesent id orci. Donec hendrerit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean sit amet arcu a turpis posuere pretium.<br><br> 

Nulla mauris odio, vehicula in, condimentum sit amet, tempus id, metus. Donec at nisi sit amet felis blandit posuere. Aliquam erat volutpat. Cras lobortis orci in quam porttitor cursus. Aenean dignissim. Curabitur facilisis sem at nisi laoreet placerat. Duis sed ipsum ac nibh mattis feugiat. Proin sed purus. Vivamus lectus ipsum, rhoncus sed, scelerisque sit amet, ultrices in, dolor. Aliquam vel magna non nunc ornare bibendum. Sed libero. Maecenas at est. Vivamus ornare, felis et luctus dapibus, lacus leo convallis diam, eget dapibus augue arcu eget arcu.<br><br>

Fusce auctor, metus eu ultricies vulputate, sapien nibh faucibus ligula, eget sollicitudin augue risus et dolor. Aenean pellentesque, tortor in cursus mattis, ante diam malesuada ligula, ac vestibulum neque turpis ut enim. Cras ornare. Proin ac nisi. Praesent laoreet ante tempor urna. In imperdiet. Nam ut metus et orci fermentum nonummy. Cras vel nunc. Donec feugiat neque eget purus. Quisque rhoncus. Phasellus tempus massa aliquet urna. Integer fringilla quam eget dolor. Curabitur mattis. Aliquam ac lacus. In congue, odio ut tristique adipiscing, diam leo fermentum ipsum, nec sollicitudin dui quam et tortor. Proin id neque ac pede egestas lacinia. Curabitur non odio.<br><br> 

Nullam porta urna quis mauris. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec scelerisque quam vitae est. Aenean vitae diam at erat pellentesque condimentum. Duis pulvinar nisl sed orci. Vivamus turpis nisi, volutpat in, placerat et, pharetra nec, eros. Suspendisse tellus metus, sodales non, venenatis a, ultrices auctor, erat. In ut leo nec elit mattis pellentesque. Sed eros elit, cursus accumsan, sollicitudin a, iaculis quis, diam. Pellentesque fermentum, pede a nonummy varius, ligula velit laoreet erat, et lacinia nibh nulla sit amet nunc. Suspendisse at turpis quis augue pellentesque pretium. Nunc condimentum elit semper felis.<br><br> 

Duis imperdiet diam pharetra nisi. Fusce accumsan. Fusce adipiscing, felis non ornare egestas, risus elit placerat mauris, in mollis ante erat quis nisi. Quisque sed ipsum. Nulla facilisi. Donec arcu erat, sodales quis, cursus eget, posuere eget, tellus. Vestibulum eu risus. Curabitur adipiscing, odio in pretium feugiat, nulla magna vehicula lorem, at placerat tortor nisl eget velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Suspendisse mollis fermentum massa. </div>
```

Comment: I still have the same problem as I had earlier. I want to add another div above the #a and #b ones. But as soon as I add the div it messes up #a because of the "position: fixed" thing.

Comment: I pretty much want the same thing as the website that I linked in my post has. It starts with with the big hand with the name inside of it, and when you scroll down it brings you to the split screen where only the right div can scroll down.

Comment: Well this is new for me, I didn't see it explained on the question.

Comment: I originally tried it without the new div, but as soon as I added it the whole #a just disappeared.I'm pretty sure it's just below my screen because of the fixed position, but I have no idea how to make it work as on the website that I linked.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it's helpful to you. Thanks.

```css
.aboutTitle {
display: table-cell;
background-color: red;
float: left;
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
position:fixed;
}

.aboutText {
display: table-cell;
background-color: orange;
float: left;
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
position:absolute;
right:0px;
}
```

```html
<section class="about">
<div class="aboutTitle">
    about
</div>

<div class="aboutText">
    <p style="font-size: 50px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I've used your code and it doesn't seem to be working the way your snippet is working. This is what's it's looking like right now: http://prntscr.com/ab2t6p Any idea why mine is not working like your snippet?

Comment: Wait for some time. I am trying to make whole same thing as website that you given for reference. I don't have much knowedge about jquery like any experience person. As soon as I finished. I will post it. Thank you.

Comment: I have found the problem, but I've now stumbled across another problem. I'll edit my post so you can see.

Comment: how to use home section that you want ? you want to stick it to the top?

Comment: I pretty much want to use it the same way as the website that I linked in my post.

Comment: so it's working.Just add the same code that you posted. I am not getting your problem.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ab3bmf This is what it looks like with the code that I posted. The bottom-left box should have a red background and the word "about" in it. When I delete my homesection it gives me the red background and about, but it disappears again when I bring the home section back. I use Chrome btw.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting to spot this after doing this same thing last week.

I use nested flex boxes to achieve this.  Here is a very redacted version of what I used for a map pop up.  With a little work you can also make it rearrange for a cell phone or even a tablet, but I leave that to you.

**CSS**

```
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    align-items: stretch;
    width: 600px;
    height: 340px;
}
#header {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: orange;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #CCC;
}
#content {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row norwap;
    align-items: stretch;
    min-height: 0;
}
#navbar {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 0px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
#main {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: flex; flex-flow:
    column nowrap;
    align-items: stretch;
}
#map {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: auto;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blueviolet;
}
#desc {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Super Nested Flexbox Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li>Douglas Adams</li>
                <li>Sarah Jane Smith</li>
                <li>Patrick Thourton</li>
                <li>Oscar Wilde</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="map"></div>
            <div id="desc">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam quis sem maximus, lobortis lacus ut, finibus enim. Donec diam dolor, fermentum sit amet elementum vitae, congue ut lectus. Nullam maximus neque nisl, eu tristique mi accumsan elementum. Phasellus quis nulla urna. Phasellus nec mauris maximus, elementum ante id, tristique velit. Praesent luctus placerat aliquam. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas vitae turpis ut metus lobortis aliquet. Cras sollicitudin tempus hendrerit. Quisque rhoncus eleifend ex, at finibus elit ultrices nec. Fusce tincidunt diam eu nisi iaculis vestibulum. Suspendisse potenti. Cras facilisis lobortis nunc quis faucibus. Vestibulum aliquet nulla ac tortor molestie, a cursus mi tincidunt. Proin faucibus dictum est, sit amet convallis elit convallis in. 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note the use of "min-height: 0;" which is necessary for FireFox's implementation of Flexbox.

Hope this helps!